# Moment.js How to display time remaining in day (with timezone offset)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to display time remaining until midnight, like this:
22 hours 48 minutes 12 seconds remaining

To make things a bit more difficult, this should show in the UTC+2 timezone.
Is this possible in plain javascript or easier with momentjs?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: What did you tried so far? See moment [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

Comment: Always use a library for timezone things. Here's a [great video](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY) explaining why you should never handle timezones yourself.

Comment: @SumnerEvans as far as I know moment.js is a library for timezone things and more ;)

Comment: @schrej the OP asked whether using a library or pure JS is best.

Comment: @SumnerEvans Oh sorry, I didn't see that! But I would agree, a library is the better option.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let now = moment();
let timeDiff = moment(now).utcOffset(120).endOf('day') - now;

let dur = moment.duration(timeDiff);

console.log(`${dur.hours()} hrs ${dur.minutes()} min ${dur.seconds()} sec until midnight.`);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Like others have commented, when it comes to timezone stuff, definitely better to utilize existing, tested libraries. JavaScript unfortunately has very weak native support for useful datetime manipulation - it would be very hard (and error-prone) to implement the same thing using native Dates.

Comment: Also, consider whether you *always* want UTC+2, or if you're actually trying to target a specific time zone that may have a different offset depending on daylight savings, etc.

In that case, you'd want to also use moment's optional timezone library.

Comment: let timeDiff = moment(now).utcOffset(120).endOf('day').diff(now); (use diff instead of minus if you get errors in your typescript code).